# Activity Intent-Filter Action Name for Launcher from Different Package

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest, launcher

I'm befuddled.

I have two activities from different package, let's say, "com.exampleone.a" and "com.exampletwo.b". They are under the same project.

In the single manifest xml, due to efficiency reasons, I had chosen to declare "com.exampleone" as the package, i.e.,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.exampleone"
          ....../>
```

As such, for the intent-filter on the other activity i use...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.exampletwo.b" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

So in my program, when I want to go to com.exampletwo.b, I'd use...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.exampletwo.b");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

---

As it happens (yeah, life), I eventually decided I had to use activity "com.exampletwo.b" as the launcher. So I tried doing changing it into a launcher...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.exampletwo.b" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

...which doesn't work (it gives the 'No Launcher Activity Found' error). And I can't rename the action as...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

...because then I'd have trouble referring to this activity (note that throughout the project I've been using "com.exampletwo.b" for my intents).

Is there a way that I can get the launcher working, preferably without having to rename anything?

I figured I might get this working by creating a dummy launcher activity, but is there an easier way of working this out?

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't make an activity from you can choose other activities to start.
Something like LauncherActivity, FromOnePackageAct,FromTwoPackageAct.
Then in LauncherActivity you can jump to other:

```
public class LauncherActivity...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FromOnePackageAct.class);//here´s the trick
    from.startActivity(intent);
//  from.finish(); this is optional
```

Hope this can provide you an idea :-)